# Why are shadows not snapping to the objects?

Tags: unity, shadows

I'm using a directional light in Unity to cast shadows. However, the shadows don't appear to be "snapped" to the objects creating them. The object appears to be floating in mid air while it actually isn't.

How do I "snap" the shadow to the objects so it looks like it's actually on the ground?

[image]

Comment: I don't use Unity but this clearly looks like Peter-Panning caused by too large of a bias

Comment: That actually was the case (I had bias on 2, changed it to 0)... So easy, feel kind of dumb right now. Well then, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it was already answered, I was working on my answer. Well, it's here for future readers. I still suggest you edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Bias property on your light. From [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Light.html) (specifically the "Shadow Mapping and the Bias Property" section):

> It is a mistake to set the bias too high, however, since areas of a
>   shadow near to the object casting it can then sometimes be falsely
>   illuminated. This effect is known as “Peter Panning” (i.e. **the
>   disconnected shadow makes the object look as if it is flying above the
>   ground**, like Peter Pan).

[image]

I suggest you lower the bias value. But don't lower it too much! If it's too low you'll get shadow acne.

[image]

Comment: I still get this effect for some objects, even when lowering bias to 0. A cube or a 3d model of a person both offsets the shadow incorrectly even at 0 bias. The person looks exactly like the top screenshot, appearing to hover in the air, although I've made sure that's not the case. A sphere or a cylinder seems to work fine though.